# Intuit QBD v2 customer query not returning correct open balance

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am just getting started with the QBD v2 .net sdk and am starting out by trying a simple customer query.  I have no filters on the query and simply bind the returned list to a grid.  My problem is, I am binding OpenBalance.Amount to a column and it is returning 0 instead of the proper amount.  Is there something in the query object that I need to set to get the proper open balance, or possibly something that needs to change in the sync process from my file to the Intuit cloud?  The code that I am using is simply:

```
CustomerQuery custQuery = new CustomerQuery();

IEnumerable<Customer> oCustomers = custQuery.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(context);
```

Like I said, the query is returning the customers I expect to see but the open balances are not correct.  Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: If you are 100% sure that Sync Manager is running (so things are synced) and you're still seeing incorrect open balances, then you should submit your XML request and XML response to Intuit as a support ticket so they can look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity is likely in an error state. You can check by executing a query and setting ErroredObjectsOnly=true.

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0015_Retrieving_Objects#Objects_in_Error_State

If the entity is in error state, you can query for the specific reason using the SyncStatus API:

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus

From there, you will need to delete or revert the object in error state, depending on if a sync has occurred.

Delete (sync has not occurred):

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/Deleting_an_Object

If a successful sync did occur with the entity at least once, but then an Update pushed it into error state, you will need to do a Revert:

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/Reverting_an_Object

You can also try doing an Update (Mod) directly on the entity in error state once you know the reason from the SyncStatus API, but it is not documented so it may not work.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  None of my objects are in an error state, however, when I used the synchronized filter I found all the objects in a non-synchronized state which explains the wrong balance issue.  I will do some more research to see how to get them in a sync'd state.  Thanks again for the guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to call 'Get by ID' api from apiexplorer and check if you are facing the same issue.
Link - http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com

You can also refer the following link to get some related code snippets. 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0200_ipp_java_devkit/0800_crud_examples

Comment: I used the apiexplorer and received the same response XML that I get from my other query.  The balance is being returned as 0 when it shows in the file as 5,040.77.  The customer is active and clicking the open balance link in the customer center shows the 5,070.77 amount.  It seems like the sync manager is not sending this data to the Intuit cloud for some reason.  Is there a setting in QB that I should be looking at to make sure all information is being sync'd?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there are some jobs associated with that customer record.
Can you please try to query using the customer filter endpoint with 'OpenBalanceWithJobs' flag set as true.

```
<CustomerQuery xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
  <OpenBalanceWithJobs>true</OpenBalanceWithJobs>
</CustomerQuery >
```

Endpoint - https://internal.services.qdc.intuit.com/sb/customer/v2/

In the response xml, you should get the open balance related to the job.

```
...
<OpenBalanceWithJobs>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<Amount>12420.98</Amount>
</OpenBalanceWithJobs>
...
```

You can try the apiexplorer tool to test this use case.
Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBD

Please let us know if it resolves this issue.

Thanks